# ng build frozen on live ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu

Im trying to ng build the source of an angular app in the www directory of apache on a live ububtu server hosted on digital oceon. The command gets to

```
compiling @angular/core: es2015 as esm2015
```

And gets stuck there till kingdom come. This app is building very well on my local windows machine. Im not an expert on linux but is there something im missing, please help me correct this

Comment: Probably Droplet Memory related.

Comment: So i cant deploy an angular app on a 1gb ram server?

Comment: npm/webpack builds need more ram - I would assume. you can build it on another machine - an deploy it to the 1GB server. Fingers-Crossed.

Comment: Ok @madflow you were indeed right. I upgraded my droplet to a 2gb ram and it compiles flawlessly